# Получить данные c сайта и записать их в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, csv, случайные-числа

Задание следующее :

Написать функцию, которая принимает в виде параметра целое число - количество цитат с сайта http://forismatic.com/ru/.
Надо получить ровно столько не повторяющихся цитат с данными и сохранить их в csv файл.

Заголовки файла: Author, Quote, URL.
Если автор не указан, цитату не брать.
Перед сохранением в csv, записи отсортировать по автору (в алфавитном порядке).

У меня получилось вернуть цитаты и сохранить их в файл, но вот сортировка по алфавиту и взять цитаты только с автором не получается.

Мои наработки:

```py
url = "http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/"


def choise_random_int(int):
   for number in range(int):
      params = {"method": "getQuote",
        "format": "json",
        "key": number,
        "lang": "ru"}
      response = requests.get(url, params=params)
      result = response.json()
      for key in result:
         print(f"{key} ------ {result[key]}")


myData = [choise_random_int(3)]


def without_author(myData):
    om = [myData.get(key) for key in ('quoteText', 'quoteAuthor', 'quoteLink')]
    return om


def sortByAlphabet(quoteAuthor):
    return quoteAuthor[0]

newList = sorted(_, key=sortByAlphabet)


def save_in_file_csv(FILE_PATH,):
    with open(FILE_PATH, "w", encoding="UTF-8"):
        writer = csv.writer(FILE_PATH)
        writer.writerows(newList)
```

В итоге мне нужно получить данные в таком виде:

quoteText ------ Зорко одно лишь сердце
quoteAuthor ------ Антуан Экзюпери
quoteLink ------ http://forismatic.com/ru/b2da20d992/
quoteText ------ Какой смысл в том, чтобы только знать?
quoteAutor ------ Шри Ауробиндо
quoteLink ------ http://forismatic.com/ru/b2da20d997/

Comment: Попробуйте использовать библиотеку `Pandas`, там и сортировать можно и в `csv` выводить.

Comment: Не хотелось бы использовать сторонние библиотеки, сделать все проще хочется , но спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Если возник новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, а не сносите все из существующего вопроса. Тем более, что менять полностью вопрос, к которому уже есть ответы (тем самым делая ответы неверными) - дурной тон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- не используйте зарезервированные слова в качестве имен переменных;
- используйте while если нужен бесконечный цикл с выходом по условию;
- по-максимуму рандомизируйте params['key'];

```
import random

def choise_random_int(qty):
    unique_quotes = []
    params = {
        "method": "getQuote",
        "format": "json",
        "key": randint(0, 99999),
        "lang": "ru"
    }
    
    while len(unique_quotes) < qty:
        response = requests.get(url, params=params)
        result = response.json()

        if not result['quoteAuthor']:
            continue

        if result['quoteText'] not in [q['quoteText'] for q in unique_quotes]:
            unique_quotes.append(result)

    unique_quotes = sorted(unique_quotes, key=lambda k: k['quoteAuthor'])

    return unique_quotes
```

Вызов `choise_random_int(7)` вернет семь уникальных цитат с quoteAuthor, отсортированных по имени автора:

```
[
    {'quoteText': 'Кто изучил науки, а к делу их не применил, словно тот, кто арык прорыл, а поле не засеял, или засеял, да урожаем не воспользовался. ', 'quoteAuthor': 'Алишер Навои', 'senderName': '', 'senderLink': '', 'quoteLink': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/b56ca7a1f1/'}, 
    {'quoteText': 'Управляй своим настроением, ибо оно если не повинуется, то повелевает. ', 'quoteAuthor': 'Гораций', 'senderName': '', 'senderLink': '', 'quoteLink': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/86b337312a/'}, 
    {'quoteText': 'Мир преобразуют те, кто смог преобразовать себя, зная, что величайшее мастерство берет начало из контроля ума. Когда ум становится послушным слугой человека, весь мир ляжет у его ног.', 'quoteAuthor': 'Инаят Хан Хидаят', 'senderName': '', 'senderLink': '', 'quoteLink': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/e0d296ebf1/'}, 
    {'quoteText': 'Воин должен научиться отдавать себе отчет в каждом действии, сделать каждое действие осознанным. Ведь мы пришли сюда ненадолго, и времени, которое нам отпущено, слишком мало для того, чтобы прикоснуться ко всем чудесам этого странного мира.', 'quoteAuthor': 'Карлос Кастанеда', 'senderName': '', 'senderLink': '', 'quoteLink': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/9902458aa1/'}, 
    {'quoteText': 'Общего у людей только одно: все они разные. ', 'quoteAuthor': 'Роберт Зенд', 'senderName': '', 'senderLink': '', 'quoteLink': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/6be6670498/'}, 
    {'quoteText': 'Тот, кто может и бездействует, хуже того, кто не может, но пытается что-то сделать. ', 'quoteAuthor': 'Уильям Блейк', 'senderName': '', 'senderLink': '', 'quoteLink': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/4d05b1c324/'}, 
    {'quoteText': 'Слово — врата ума. Если держать их открытыми, ум ускользнет наружу. ', 'quoteAuthor': 'Хун Цзычен', 'senderName': '', 'senderLink': '', 'quoteLink': 'http://forismatic.com/ru/83f81e6de9/'}
]
```

А дальше выводите, сохраняйте, отправляйте дальше на обработку etc.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое и хорошего вечера)